# ES6 Format Data from LEFT Join

Tags: arrays, json, for-loop, ecmascript-6

Supposedly, I have a data returned from an LEFT JOIN query and I want to format it via Javascript. What's an ES6 way to accomplish this?

Let's say I have this data:

```
[
    {
      "process_name": "Process 1",
      "bom_qty": 1.000000,
      "wip_qty": 20,
      "material_name": "Material 1",
      "material_id": "id 1",
      "process_id": 1
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 2",
      "bom_qty": 1.000000,
      "wip_qty": 11,
      "material_name": "Material 2",
      "material_id": "id 2",
      "process_id": 2
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 2",
      "bom_qty": 0.000003,
      "wip_qty": 11,
      "material_name": "Material 3",
      "material_id": "id 3",
      "process_id": 2
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 3",
      "bom_qty": "",
      "wip_qty": 58,
      "material_name": "Material 4",
      "material_id": "id 4",
      "process_id": 3
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 4",
      "bom_qty": "",
      "wip_qty": 58,
      "material_name": false,
      "material_id": "",
      "process_id": 4
    }
]
```

For every materials, there is a row entry in the query.

And I want to convert it to something where the rows that are having the same processes will be made into one, but the different materials are placed inside an array of objects inside it:

```
[
    {
      "process_name": "Process 1",
      "wip_qty": 20,
      "material": [
            {
                "name": "Material 1",
                "id": "id 1",
                "qty": 1.000000
            }
        ],
      "process_id": 1
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 2",
      "wip_qty": 11,
      "material": [
            {
                "name": "Material 2",
                "id": "id 2",
                "qty": 1.000000
            },
            {
                "name": "Material 3",
                "id": "id 3",
                "qty":  0.000003
            },
        ],
      "process_id": 2
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 3",
      "wip_qty": 58,
        "material": [
            {
                "name": "Material 4",
                "id": "id 4",
                "qty": ""
            }
        ],
      "process_id": 3
    },
    {
      "process_name": "Process 4",
      "wip_qty": 58,
      "material": [
            {
                "name": false,
                "id": "",
                "qty": ""
            }
      ],
      "process_id": 4
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` and create an object with `process_id` as key. For each unique key, create an object and add the desired property. After that, extract all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
var data = [ { "process_name": "Process 1", "bom_qty": 1.000000, "wip_qty": 20, "material_name": "Material 1", "material_id": "id 1", "process_id": 1 }, { "process_name": "Process 2", "bom_qty": 1.000000, "wip_qty": 11, "material_name": "Material 2", "material_id":"id 2", "process_id": 2 }, { "process_name": "Process 2", "bom_qty": 0.000003, "wip_qty": 11, "material_name": "Material 3", "material_id": "id 3", "process_id": 2 }, { "process_name": "Process 3", "bom_qty": "", "wip_qty": 58, "material_name": "Material 4", "material_id": "id 4", "process_id": 3 }, { "process_name": "Process 4", "bom_qty": "", "wip_qty": 58, "material_name": false, "material_id": "", "process_id": 4 } ],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,{process_name, bom_qty, wip_qty, material_name, material_id, process_id}) => {
      r[process_id] = r[process_id] || {process_name, wip_qty, material : [], process_id};
      r[process_id].material.push({name: material_name,id: material_id, qty: bom_qty });
      return r;
    },{}));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to re-shape your collection.
Something like this:

```js
const data = [{
    "process_name": "Process 1",
    "bom_qty": 1.000000,
    "wip_qty": 20,
    "material_name": "Material 1",
    "material_id": "id 1",
    "process_id": 1
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 2",
    "bom_qty": 1.000000,
    "wip_qty": 11,
    "material_name": "Material 2",
    "material_id": "id 2",
    "process_id": 2
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 2",
    "bom_qty": 0.000003,
    "wip_qty": 11,
    "material_name": "Material 3",
    "material_id": "id 3",
    "process_id": 2
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 3",
    "bom_qty": "",
    "wip_qty": 58,
    "material_name": "Material 4",
    "material_id": "id 4",
    "process_id": 3
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 4",
    "bom_qty": "",
    "wip_qty": 58,
    "material_name": false,
    "material_id": "",
    "process_id": 4
  }
];
const newData = data.map(obj => ({
  process_name: obj.process_name,
  wip_qty: obj.wip_qty,
  material: {
    name: obj.material_name,
    id: obj.material_id,
    qty: obj.wip_qty
  }
}));

console.log(newData);
```

**Edit**
I miss understood your desired end result, i thought you only wants to re-shape the structure.
Now that i understand that you also want to combine (group) the objects i wrote another solution which uses `reduce` and `map`.

```js
const data = [{
    "process_name": "Process 1",
    "bom_qty": 1.000000,
    "wip_qty": 20,
    "material_name": "Material 1",
    "material_id": "id 1",
    "process_id": 1
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 2",
    "bom_qty": 1.000000,
    "wip_qty": 11,
    "material_name": "Material 2",
    "material_id": "id 2",
    "process_id": 2
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 2",
    "bom_qty": 0.000003,
    "wip_qty": 11,
    "material_name": "Material 3",
    "material_id": "id 3",
    "process_id": 2
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 3",
    "bom_qty": "",
    "wip_qty": 58,
    "material_name": "Material 4",
    "material_id": "id 4",
    "process_id": 3
  },
  {
    "process_name": "Process 4",
    "bom_qty": "",
    "wip_qty": 58,
    "material_name": false,
    "material_id": "",
    "process_id": 4
  }
];
const newData = data.reduce((result, proc) => {
 const foundProc = result.find(p => p.process_id === proc.process_id);
  const {bom_qty: qty,material_name: name,material_id: id, ...newProc  } = proc;
  if(!foundProc){
    result.push({
      ...newProc,
      materials: [{name, id, qty}]
    });
  } else{
   result = result.map(p => {
     if(p.process_id !== proc.process_id) return p;
      return{
       ...p,
        materials: [...p.materials, {name, id, qty}]
      }
    });
  }
 return result;
},[]);

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the array takes you halfway. You still need to create an intermediate object with process_id as key and the object as value. Then iterate over it; if the key doesn't exist, push the value to the result array; if it exists, push the material array to the existing one. Somethink like this (add it right after the previous code by Sagiv):

```
const tmpObj = {}
newData.forEach(e => {
  if (tmpObj[e.process_id]) {
    tmpObj[e.process_id].material.push(e.material[0])
  } else {
    tmpObj[e.process_id] = e
  }
})
const resultArray = []
for (let key of Object.keys(tmpObj)) {
  resultArray.push(tmpObj[key])
}
console.log(resultArray)
```